# Tensorflow trained model speed

Tags: python, opencv, tensorflow, deep-learning, training-data

I'm a Tensorflow newby and I'm trying to train a 1 class model for object detection. In particular I'm trying to recognize an arrow like the following:

[image]

I need a very fast recognition so I started wondering if a pre-trained model can contain such kind of shape.
Unfortunately didn't find anything similar and therefor I started with my own training of the arrow using as model the faster_rcnn_inception_v2_coco_2018_01_28.

I'm using his pipeline config, and I'm using his fine_tune_checkpoint as well, is this right considering that I have to train a completely different object?

The result is a training with a very good accuracy but very low speed. I need to increase the framerate and I didn't understand yet if the less is the "training loss" the more is the "object recognition speed", or not.

Any suggestion on how could I speedup the detection?

Comment: First thing that comes to my mind: The Faster-RCNN model might be an overkill for the task of recognizing a plain arrow. Maybe trying object detecting models made for real time use (like YOLO, or SSD 'Single Shot Detector') can be an alternative.
If you are not bound to using a NN, you might also consider using simpler approaches like OpenCV's Haar Cascade Classifier, which should be sufficient for recognizing simple shapes.

Comment: Thank you, do you thing that the OpenCV HCC would detect the arrow in his different positions? The final need is to follow a robot into the space. I will stick the arrow on the head of the robot and with a camera placed on a 3m height 45° I need to recognize the arrow and track the robot movements. Do you have a better solution for that task?

Comment: So you're not only having a detection problem, but you also want to detect rotation. (Not sure if Faster-RCNN is able to do that, neither HCC)
It might be sufficient to track the position of the robot and estimate the direction from its relative movement.

Comment: Btw: There is a model called Mask-RCNN [See: https://github.com/matterport/Mask_RCNN] (extension of Faster-RCNN), which yields the shape of the detected object as well. From there you can maybe find the rotation of the arrow. But is slow in detection time due to its complex architecture.

Comment: about the direction i will apply a sort of post processing with openCv to the arrow bounding box, for example I will calculate the area with the highest yellow pixel density, and I will suppose the highest one is the head of the arrow and therefore the direction of the robot

Comment: Btw I was wondering also what is the easiest shape to recognize with whatever computer vision system that can express the position and the direction once applied on the head of the robot. I came up with the arrow but any suggestion is appreciated. :)

Comment: Easy shapes to recognize are AprilTags [ https://april.eecs.umich.edu/software/apriltag ] or similar codes for example. They are made for easy recognition and can contain orientation information. Plus there are robust libraries for many languages out there. If you want to design a shape on your own, it might be helpful to use two colors for orientation detection: A yellow line with a red dot at one end might be easier than a single color arrow.

Comment: AprilTags are an incredible hint, thank you very much! I cannot understand which is the best recognizable tag family from the distance, do you know if the greater is the bit size the harder is the detection? Does the hamming distance influence as well?

Comment: Sorry I never worked with AprilTags, nor do I know about its detection details. It was only an idea coming to my mind. But I suppose there are studies about detection rates out there waiting to be found by googling :) I imagine the number of pixels in your image representing one bit of the aprilTag is crucial.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I'm using his pipeline config, and I'm using his fine_tune_checkpoint
>   as well, is this right considering that I have to train a completely
>   different object?

Yes! Every time you want to change the output of a deep NN, you should take a pretrained model. Training a model from scratch can take several weeks and you will never be able to generate enough data on your own. Taking a pretrained model and fine-tuning it is a way to go.

> I didn't understand yet if the
>   less is the "training loss" the more is the "object recognition
>   speed", or not.

No. Training loss just tells you how good your model performs with respect to the training set.

The issue you are having is a classic speed vs. accuracy trade-off. I encourage you to take a look at [this table](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/research/object_detection/g3doc/detection_model_zoo.md) and find a model which is fast enough for you (i.e. lowest run-time) but have decent accuracy. I would first check `SSD` here.

Comment: Thank you, I'm now trying with the ssdlite_mobilenet_v2_coco_2018_05_09 that should be faster. I edited into the pipeline.config the "num_classes" value putting it to 1 (as I need to recognize the arrow only) is this right as well?

Comment: You will also need some negative examples as well. If you created your data set you will need to include some images which are not the arrow. So basically you will need to have 2 classes: arrow & not arrow.

Comment: by now with 1 class and the ssdlite mobilnet v2 I have: loss = 2.5471618, step = 666 ...is this so high loss normal?

Comment: The number you are seeing, well, doesn't mean a lot. The important part is that the training loss is decreasing (as well as validation loss!).

Answer (score 0):

> The result is a training with a very good accuracy but very low speed.

How much FPS does your algorithm perform?
Since you already have prepared dataset, I would suggest using Tiny-Yolo which performs 244 FPS on COCO dataset https://pjreddie.com/darknet/yolo/

Preparing training dataset for Tiny-Yolo is very easy if you use this [repository](https://github.com/AlexeyAB/darknet#how-to-train-tiny-yolo-to-detect-your-custom-objects)

And

> I didn't understand yet if the less is the "training loss" the more is the "object recognition speed"

Training lost has nothing to do with speed.